# How to set default date (in this format "dd/mm/yy") in text box which is attached with a datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to search depending upon a date in the textbox.But initially i want to fill that textbox with a default date(ie,today).

Comment: placeholder="dd/mm/yy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("#my_dp").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
var t = new Date();
var formattedDate = t.getDate() + "/" + (t.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + t.getFullYear();
$("#my_dp").datepicker("setDate", formattedDate);
```

Comment: i was unaware of your machines culture. updated answer

Comment: what is `setDate` here ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
    });
});
```

datepicker is your date control
refer this url http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Answer (score 1):

I got another way

```
$("#startDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date()));
```